# Set a custom CollectionViewCells label in ViewControllers cellForItemAt indexPath method

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to set my Custom collection view cells UILabel text with the following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: AlbumCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AlbumCollectionViewCell

    //set label text
    cell.albumLabel?.text = self.objects[indexPath.item]

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 51, b: 51, g: 51)
    return cell
}
```

But it results in empty labels on my cells. My cell label is returning nil but everything looks connected between my xib and collectionviewcell subclass.

Here are the xib-code file connections:

[image]

and the custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

class AlbumCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var albumImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var albumLabel: UILabel?
}
```

Comment: **But it results in empty labels on my cells. My cell label is returning nil**, your labels are visible or it is getting crash because its nil ?

Comment: Please add brief of your error.

Comment: @SharadChauhan the labels are empty, and if i print the cell.albumLabel?.text it prints nil.

Answer (score 0):

check delegate and dataSource protocol of collectionView is connected or not ?
if not then add this code in viewDidLoad() method

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```